# Comparar string con Time.now en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo el modelo Casa, con el atributo pintada_el.

Este campo está definido en la tabla como string en este formato dd-mm-yyyy, un ejemplo típico sería este valor "20-06-2021"), que se leería como 20 de junio de 2021.

El asunto es que necesito saber que casas ya están pintadas (menor al dia de hoy) o que se van a pintar (igual o mayor al día de hoy) basados en este campo en string llamado pintada_el.

Intenté esto, pero no funciona:
en el modelo de Casa creé este método.

```
def pintada_el
  Date.parse(self[:pintada_el]).strftime('%Y%m%d')
end
```

y en el helper tengo está asignación que no camina:

```
casas_por_pintar = Casa.where("pintada_el > TIMESTAMP 'now'").size
casas_pintadas = Casa.where("pintada_el <= TIMESTAMP 'now'").size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que deberías hacer la comparación de fechas a nivel de base de datos, por tanto es ahí donde deberías transformar el texto a fecha. No dijiste cual motor de BD estás usando, pero en PostgreSQL podrías usar algo como:

```
Casa.where("TO_DATE(pintada_el,'DD-MM-YYYY') > ?", Date.today)
```

Comment: Es postgresql..